# Oracle 11g - REGEXP_REPLACE - Subexpressions/different matches

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db1bd/49/0

I'm working on a query that returns an object's DN:`(cn=name,ou=folder,dc=hostname,dc=com)`

My goal is to return this information in a "prettier" output akin to AD:`(name\folder\hostname.com)`

I've accomplished this in a clunky way:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TEST, '.*CN=(.+?),DC=.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'i'), ',OU=', '\', 1, 0, 'i') -- grab everything between CN= and DC=, replace with \'s --
|| '\' || 
REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(TEST, REGEXP_INSTR(TEST, ',DC=', 1, 1, 0, 'i')+4),',DC=','.', 1, 0, 'i') -- grab everything after DC=, replace with .'s --
```

While that works I'm not thrilled with how overly complicated it is (and that it involves having to stitch two regex'd strings together).

I started clean and realized I was doing too much to get what I wanted and my starting point is now here:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(test, '(,?(cn=|ou=)(.+?),)', '\3\')
```

I *think* I have a good understanding of how this one works but if I add an additional (...) it breaks what I already have working and returns the entire string.  I've read that Oracle's regex engine is not as advanced as some others, but I'm struggling to grasp the order of how things are evaluated.

Example Input (can have multiple OUs/DCs):

`cn=name,ou=subgroup,ou=group,dc=accounts,dc=hostname,dc=com
cn=name,ou=group,dc=hostname,dc=com`

Expected Output

`name\subgroup\group\accounts.hostname.com
name\group\hostname.com`

The data coming in is dynamic and never a set number of OUs or DCs.

Comment: What about http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db1bd/67/0? You haven't specified expected output, so I'm just guessing that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @ctwheels Expected output format is listed above: `name\folder\hostname.com`

Your example does not work if there are more than 2 (dc=): `cn=name,ou=hello,dc=accounts,dc=hostname,dc=com`

Instead it combines them together `name\hello\accountshostname.com`.  I'm beginning to think that this can't be accomplished with a single REGEXP_REPLACE and will require multiples (like your example).

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. It seems you want to replace (most) `,xx=` with backslash; but at the end, it seems you want to replace with dot, not backslash. That seems to be the case for the `dc` attributes, except that in your last sample string you have five values, all for `cn` (there is no `dc` in that string). So - if you need help, you will need to explain EXACTLY what you need.

Comment: @mathguy Provided input examples and expected output.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew That's exactly what I was looking for, as well as some assurance that this couldn't be accomplished with just one regex.  Thanks for help.

Comment: What should the expected output be for the record, `cn=group1,cn=group2,cn=group3,cn=hostname,cn=com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        test, 
        '(^|,)(cn|ou)=([^,]*)(,dc=)?', 
        '\3\\'), 
    ',dc=', 
    '.') 
FROM regexTest
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/217a61/7).

The first `(^|,)(cn|ou)=([^,]*)(,dc=)?` regex matches `,` or start of string, then `cn` or `ou`, then `=`, then captures into Group 3 zero or more chars other than a comma, and then matches an optional `,dc=` substring (thus, removing the first instance of `,dc=`). The replacement is Group 3 contents and a backslash.

So, the second operation is easy, just replace all `,dc=` with `.`, you do not even need a regex for this.

Answer (score -1):

May be something like that:

```
SELECT nvl(regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
      nullif(
        regexp_replace(test, '^cn=(.+?),DC=(.+?)$', '\1 \2',1,1,'i') 
        , test
      ) , ' |,(CN|OU)=', '\\', 1, 0,'i'
    ), ',DC=', '.', 1, 0,'i'
    ),test) result
FROM regexTest
```

This query does not change the input if there is no `DC=`.